# xCode simulator won't show keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

If I start up a blank app (single view application) and simply put a UITextField into the NIB, everything is fine: a keyboard will show up once I click the UITextField in the simulator.

If I start up the app I'm working on at the moment, the keyboard will not show up (as if I had turned on simulate Hardware keyboard) and I am not able to enter any text at all. If I run the same app on my phone, however, the keyboard will show up and I can enter text as usual.

I'm sure it has to do with my code as the blank app will show a keyboard on the simulator. My set up is as follows: I have a RootViewController and then add another ViewController. In this ViewController I add yet another ViewController (where I want the UITextField to be) like so:

```
if (self.addNotebook == nil) {

    NSLog(@"create...");
    AddNotebookViewController *avc = [[AddNotebookViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.addNotebook = avc;
    [avc release];

}

[self.view addSubview:addNotebook.view];
```

There is hardly anything in this new ViewController:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AddNotebookViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
}

...
```

The xib is set up as follows:

One simple UITextField

File's Owner Class = AddNotebookViewController

File's Owner Outlet view = view

Text Field delegate = File's owner

So I don't understand why the keyboard doesn't pop up in the simulator while it does on my phone... any suggestions would be very much welcome!

Comment: Where is the definition with the IBOutlet for the textfield in the h-file?

Comment: @ott well, there isn't one as it is not strictly need to display the keyboard. I tried to put it in and wired it up, but it won't change anything either. Keyboard is still not coming up. Perhaps something to do with my several ViewControllers? But keyboard is definitively not hidden- I can't type anything at all (in the simulator). And I can type wonderfully (and as expected) on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the problem. It has to do with iOS 5, so I guess we can't really discuss this here. If I run the app on iOS 5, I won't see the keyboard on the phone or on the simulator.

If I rung the app on iOS 4 or on Simulator iOS 4 everything is fine and everyone happy.

I still don't know why this is so... I guess I need to head over to the apple discussion forum for these kind if questions?

Thanks